# Upload not works correctly, on new server php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

i really dont understand what happen here, its works on most of servers but now i cant put this to working, and i dont have any idea what happen.

```
<?php

 require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/inc/config.php";
 require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/inc/class.upload.php";
 $upload_folder = dirname(__FILE__);


  if(isset($_POST['filename'])) {

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));
$content = file_get_contents($_POST['file'], false, $context);
$fileName = $_POST['filename'];
$ext = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);
$saved_file = str_replace( '.' . $ext, '', $fileName );
$saved_file .= '_' . crypt($saved_file) . '.' . $ext;
$saved_file = str_replace('/', '', $saved_file);
while( @ file_exists($upload_folder.'/'.$saved_file) ) {
    $saved_file = str_replace( '.' . $ext, '', $saved_file );
    $saved_file .= crypt($saved_file) . '.' . $ext;
}


 if(file_put_contents($upload_folder.'/'.$saved_file, $content, 0, $context)) {

    $file_name_save = $upload_folder.'/'.$saved_file;
    $handle = new Upload($file_name_save);

    if ($handle->uploaded){
        $imageName = $handle->file_src_name;
        $handle->file_new_name_body     = date("Ymdhis").md5($imageName);
        $handle->mime_check             = true;
        $handle->allowed                = array('image/*');
        $handle->image_convert          = 'jpg';

        if(($handle->image_src_x > 900) || ($handle->image_src_y > 900)){
            $handle->image_resize   = true;
            $handle->image_ratio    = true;
            $handle->image_x        = 900;
            $handle->image_y        = 600;
        }

        $handle->Process(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/img/Noticias/');

        if ($handle->processed){
            $NoticiaFoto_Imagem = $handle->file_dst_name;

            $Sql = "INSERT INTO tabnoticiasfotos (Noticia_Id, NoticiaFoto_Nome, NoticiaFoto_Ordem, NoticiaFoto_Imagem)  VALUES ('".$_POST['ID']."', '', 'NULL', '$NoticiaFoto_Imagem') ";
            fputs($fp,$Sql);
            $Query = mysql_query($Sql,$Conn) or die(mysql_error($Conn));
            @unlink($file_name_save);
        }

    }
}
echo $saved_file;
$_SESSION["varMensagem"]["css"] = "success";
$_SESSION["varMensagem"]["mensagem"] = "Fotos Enviadas com sucesso.";
exit();
 }
?>
```

this get a array of images (jquery upload) and do all the work.

but on the new server, nothing works

the pictures are uploaded to the same folder the file are and the new name looks crazy and dont save any information on my database.

I posted before all the tests

the problem is here

```
 if(file_put_contents($upload_folder.'/'.$saved_file, $content, 0, $context)) {
```

returns false, so then dont finish the upload.

so for me the problem is here and i think is about the server configuration.
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));

sorry guys im not a expert

Comment: "nothing works" well that's helpful. you have to at lest do some debugging your self.

Comment: There must be some error messages - check the server logs, add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script to see them logged to screen

Comment: did you check ownership of directory?  try apache

Comment: Since when do file uploads use $_POST? Unless you're pasting a file's contents into a textbox, the upload info should be in $_FILES.

Comment: what is is supose to happen? "$upload_folder = dirname(__FILE__);" => "the pictures are uploaded to the same folder", and "$saved_file .= '_' . crypt($saved_file) . '.' . $ext;" => the new name looks crazy, and maybe '$NoticiaFoto_Imagem' should have had " insted of ' so the var value gets sent to database

Comment: Im sorry, i posted before all the tests, i have updated the question with more info i got..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

resolves the issue.